# I am trying to understand why this code is using is_callable() and call_user_func_array

Tags: php, wordpress

I have taken over a WordPress website and have found some of the PHP code a little over my head. The site has an API which calls JSON data from a 3rd party, decodes it into an array, performs some validation checks and then maps it to an array of key=>value pairs before inserting the data into into the database. I understand all the code up until it starts to perform the mapping excercise. The reason I am stuck is that it is using is_callable() and call_user_func_array() on what seems to be the iterator in the foreach loop. I can only find documentation on this function which states it is for testing if there is a function which is callable.

$mapping is the multi-dimension array of key=>value pairs from wp_postmeta we are interested in and $course represents an array of data from the API associated with a 3rd party course which is to be saved to the appropriate key=>value in wp_postmeta. $mapping is defined in the Class in which this function lives.

Can anyone please explain to me what is happening here. Many thanks.

```
private function make_mapped_value($mapping, $course) {
        if(!is_array($mapping)) return $mapping;
        $val = $course;
        foreach($mapping as $step) {
            if(is_callable($step) && !in_array($step, ['min', 'max'])) {
                $val = call_user_func_array($step, array(&$val));
               
            }
            else {
                $val = isset($val[$step]) ? $val[$step] : NULL;
               
            }
        }
        return $val;
    }
```

Comment: `is_callable()` checks if it is a function and `call_user_func_array()` calls a function. `$mapping` is a array and `$step` may a be a function. If it is not 'min' or 'max' it will be called.

Comment: That sounds correct. However, there is no function called $step. So am still not sure why this is written this way.

Comment: Hi, I think I have bottomed this. Markus is correct, because what I had missed was that in $mapping, some of the values have reference to functions.

Comment: The function is not called `$step`, which would be invalid, but in the iteration `$step` may be a function. `$myFunction = function() {};` is valid and can be called via `$myFunction();`.